# How to change XML properties in running time?

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to implementing an pending transition animation for my app.

I have over rided the pending transition with function

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.incomming, R.anim.outgoing);

and in the outgoing.xml file, it is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

and I want to change android:pivotY in running time, so how can I change this value in the java code?

I know some thing about SharedPreference, but the variables in the xml files are different from SharedPreference. So what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it seems to be impossible to change the value of the attribute at run time in the xml file. Maybe the straightforward way is to create other xml files and decide which to use as animation resources at run time.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but the pivotY value is the position on the screen, which has a big range :( Any other suggestions?